# Identify 2x2 chrome/silver emblem

Tags: part-identification

I want to know which sets this piece is from.

It's 2x2 in size, no writing on it except for an S or 8 in the hole.
I've tried googling terms such as chrome/silver indian emblem/plaque to no avail.

[image: chrome/silver emblem]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's apparently called a "Sun Disk" ([named such in an old magazine](http://www.miniland.nl/LEGOclub/lego%20mania%20magazine%20jan%20feb%201999/2.jpg)) and it appeared in 5 different sets from the 1999 Adventurers: Jungle theme.

[Minifig, Utensil Sun Disk Item No: x276](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x276#T=C&C=21)

[image]

Also it's supposed to be gold, but I think I've seen the old chrome gold discolor like this before.